# compare three variable using java script

Tags: javascript, equals, equality

Hi I have three dynamic variable

my below code is working to check if all are equal

```
if ((a == b) && (b == c)) {
   // they're all equal ...
}
```

But, I want to create a function passing three variable to check if any one variable is equal to other variable.

```
a=1;b=2;c=1;
isEqual = compareVariable(a,b,c);
```

here `isEqual` should be `true` .

How to create this function

Comment: Make a function compareVariable, put the if statement in it, in the statement you put 'return true;'

Comment: Are you sure isEqual is going to be true? I think in the above example it would be false, as 1 != 2...

Comment: yes @RichardParnaby-King - it should be true ... because a=c=1.... so it should return true

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
function compareVariable(a,b,c) {
    return a==b || b==c || c==a;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using it like this:

```
function compareVariable(a,b,c){
    var a = a;
    var b = b;
    var c = c;
    if ((a == b) && (b == c)) {
        return true
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function compareVariable(a,b,c){

if ((a == b) || (b == c) || (a == c)) {
    return true
    // any or all equal
}
else
{
    return false;
// if none of two is equal
}
}
```

Comment: Don't you think first condition is wrong in your answer?

Answer (score 0):

compareVariable(1,2,3);

```
function compareVariable(a,b,c)
{
        if ((a == b) || (b == c) || (a == c) ) {

            alert("equal");
           // they're all equal ...
        }
        else
        {
                  alert("notequal");
        }


}
```

Answer (score -1):

To create a function you need to use the reserved keyword 'function' followed by the name of the function. In this case:

```
function compareVariable(a,b,c) {
    return ((a == b) || (b == c) || (a == c));
}
```

This function will take your three variables and return boolean true if all the variables are the same.